# How to make the movie clip / buttons in AS3 work when there is no sound card

Tags: flash-cs5

I am using AS3 to develop my flash game. I have never tested this game without sound card system. The client responded back saying if there's no sound card in the system none of the movie clips and buttons of the game is working. That means the game is completely disabled but there's no problem if I have a sound card in the system. How can I make all the functionalities (movie clips, buttons) work, if there's no sound card in the system.

Thanks in advance
Nayak

Comment: There should not be any dependency on sound for the movieclips and buttons.  I'd test it on other systems to see if this is the case and find out exactly what type of configuration is giving you these results.